# Passing A Form Object As A Class Parameter In VBA

Tags: class, ms-access, vba

I have a class called **cls_Utilitario** with the method below:

```
Public Function LimparCampos(arg_form As Object)
    Dim campo As Control

    For Each campo In arg_form.Controls
        With campo
            Select Case .ControlType
                Case acComboBox, acTextBox
                    .Value = Null
            End Select
        End With
    Next campo

    Set campo = Nothing
    Set arg_form = Nothing
End Function
```

And I have the following code into the form:

```
Private Sub btnNovo_Click()
    Dim obj_Utilitario As cls_Utilitario

    Set obj_Utilitario = New cls_Utilitario
    obj_Utilitario.LimparCampos (Me.Form)

End Sub
```

Why doen't it work if I changed the argument to "Object" type? I also tryed the "Variant" and "Form" types but, unsuccessfully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the problem is in the parenthesis. Do not use them. And do not use Me.Form but Me only because the code runs in the form so Me refers to the form (hope this is the same in Access as in Excel). So I think the call should look like this: obj_Utilitario.LimparCampos Me

Comment: If you're passing `arg_form` as an Object to `LimparCampos`, then I don't think that `arg_form.Controls` is going to work unless you cast it back as a `Form`.

Comment: hi Dee and DeanOC. thanks for your quick help. it worked perfect without the parentheses like this: obj_Utilitario.LimparCampos Me.Form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
obj_Utilitario.LimparCampos (Me.Form)
```

to

```
Call obj_Utilitario.LimparCampos (Me.Form)
```

Or

```
obj_Utilitario.LimparCampos Me.Form
```

In VBA, you must not use the parentheses if you don't store the return value of the function in a variable or use the keyword `Call` as shown.

Comment: Manu, thanks a lot! it worked perfect without the parentheses like this: obj_Utilitario.LimparCampos Me.Form